# Can't seem to change the class of a span element

Tags: javascript, html

I am implementing a feature to show the content of a password field when clicking on an eye-icon on the right side of the field. 
When that item is clicked 2 things should happen:
1. The password field should become a text field
2. The icon of the eye should become a slashed out eye
3. When you click the icon again, both the other way round.

I am using Bootstrap 4.0 and Font Awesome for the general design and icons.
My current code changes the type of the password field, but not the icon on the button.

Any ideas why?

HTML part:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Passwort</label>
    <div class="input-group" id="show_hide_password">
        <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Leer lassen wenn das Passwort nicht ge&auml;ndert werden soll.">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="eyeButton" data-action="showPW"><span id="eyeLogo" class="far fa-eye"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the Javascript Part:

```
var theeyeButton = document.querySelector("[data-action=showPW]");
var theeyeLogo = document.querySelector("#eyeLogo");
var pwField = document.querySelector("#password");
//var theeyeButton = document.getElementById("showPW");
if (theeyeButton) {
    theeyeButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        if(pwField.type == "text"){
            pwField.type = "password";
            theeyeLogo.className = "far fa-eye";
        }
        else if(pwField.type == "password"){
            pwField.type = "text";
            theeyeLogo.className = "far fa-eye-slash";
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where is PHP in question?

Comment: A snipped would be great

Comment: Works on my machine? https://jsfiddle.net/hc402fx6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this js code.

```
var theeyeButton = document.querySelector("[data-action=showPW]");
var theeyeLogo = document.querySelector("#eyeLogo");
var pwField = document.querySelector("#password");
//var theeyeButton = document.getElementById("showPW");
if (theeyeButton) {
    theeyeButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
       if(pwField.type == "text"){
            pwField.type = "password";
            document.getElementById("eyeLogo").classList.remove("far", "fa-eye-slash");
            document.getElementById("eyeLogo").classList.add("far","fa-eye");
        }
        else if(pwField.type == "password"){
            pwField.type = "text";
            document.getElementById("eyeLogo").classList.remove("far","fa-eye");
            document.getElementById("eyeLogo").classList.add("far", "fa-eye-slash");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I had tried remove and add before, and it didn't work, thats why i went for .className. But your code works finde now, thanks a lot! I guess i made a mistake in my add/remove code before. You saved my day. Thanks kind sir!!!

Comment: You're welcome, please mark answer if this was helpful. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This will do

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Passwort</label>
        <div class="input-group" id="show_hide_password">
            <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Leer lassen wenn das Passwort nicht ge&auml;ndert werden soll.">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="eyeButton" data-action="showPW" value="button">button<span id="eyeLogo" class="far fa-eye-slash"></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    var theeyeButton = document.querySelector("[data-action=showPW]");
    var theeyeLogo = document.querySelector("#eyeLogo");
    var pwField = document.querySelector("#password");
    //var theeyeButton = document.getElementById("showPW");
    if (theeyeButton) {
        theeyeButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            if(pwField.type == "text"){
                pwField.type = "password";
                theeyeLogo.className = "far fa-eye-slash";
            }
            else if(pwField.type == "password"){
                pwField.type = "text";
                theeyeLogo.className = "far fa-eye";
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I am working with far actually. Looks a lot better in my project.